# Dynamic List Generated Based Off Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Quick question, I dont know if this can be done in excel only or if I will have to incorporate Access into this set up. I want to set up a dynamic list that generates subtasks for an employee based off of department. Each department gets 4 general subtasks and then they have several department specific subtasks. I have dynamic sheets that pull directly into excel. I have the subtasks listed. I thought of trying to do an array that incorporates Row counts. I want to be able to put in the Employee ID and have it pull up via vlookup the department employee name and replicate that information in a list format to display the subtasks to be uploaded.

Example: I enter 10005 it returns Joe Dirt QA department

then in the generate list it copies this criteria with the appropriate subtask as example below

```
10005 Joe Dirt 000 team Management
10005 Joe Dirt 010 development
10005 Joe Dirt 030 documentation
```

Example output:

[image]

Example Data Part 1:

[image]

Example Data Part 2:

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: ***Welcome to Stack Overflow!***  Sounds like a basic (but valuable) lesson in using `VLOOKUP`, as long as the source data is laid out in an organized manner.  Access would take longer to setup but is easier to scale to any level in the future.

Comment: Thanks! But I think I wasnt as clear as I was hoping. I want to be able to enter in multiple employee ids and generate a list similar to the one I described that will have multiple employees subtasks listed so I can do one copy and paste. Not everyone gets the same subtasks, they're department specific.

Comment: Maybe it's still unclear.  It will be much easier if you can provide sample data, both what it will be "looking up", and what the finished output should look like, more than "1 employee/3 lines". (It obviously doesn't have to be real data but it does have to be a realistic representation.)  See [mcve] and also [these great tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention in your question you want to:

> "I want to be able to put in the Employee ID and have it pull up via vlookup"
>
> "Then in the generate list it copies this criteria with the appropriate subtask as example below"

Without knowing about your data format you could try something like this, utilize this formula in a search table format such as the images posted below:

`=IFERROR(MATCH([Your Lookup Value],INDIRECT([column]&[row of previous value found]+1&[end range]),0)+[row of previous value found],"")`

This formula will `Match` the lookup value on a "custom" range and return its `Row`, the range will be set by starting on the previous `Row` found forward until the end range (`":A1000"`) in case below.

`e.g.: from image =IFERROR(MATCH($G$3,INDIRECT("A"&G5+1&":A1000"),0)+G5,"")`

The above will give you the `ROW()` of where the value you are looking for can be found, then you can simply `OFFSET()` the return value you wish (knowing the row and column).

`=OFFSET($A$1,G6-1,1)`

Images to illustrate table set up.

[image]

[image]

**Edit Implementation Help asked in comments:**

First you need set the `Row` to be utilized has reference in your case will look like this:

Set up a cell to be used has input for the `Employee ID` and point the formula to the correct lookup range and input cell.

`$N$16` - This is your input cell (the `$` means that even if you drag the formula that cell will remain the same)

`INDIRECT("K"&N18+1&":K1000")` - This is your range of the lookup, `"K"` is the column, `&N18+1&` is the result of the previous formula plus one, should point to the cell directly above (for the first formula point `N18` to an empty cell or delete it), `":K1000"` is the end of your range, if you'd like to make it bigger or smaller change the number from 1000 to `1 or 10000` depending on your data.

`+N18` - This is again pointed at the previous formula and will add the `Rows` so we can at a later stage make the `Offset` work.

`=IFERROR(MATCH($N$16,INDIRECT("K"&N18+1&":K1000"),0)+N18,"")`

Example:

[image]

Notice that the numbers resulting from this formula match with the `Rows` that contain `10005` (the value we are searching).

Next `Offset` the value you wish to return:

`=Offset([Reference],[Distance from Ref in Rows],[Distance from Ref in Columns])`

`$A$1` - Reference cell, the distances set on the rest of the formula are relative to this cell.

`AA6-1` - Distance from `$A$1` in `Rows`, The value resulting from the `Lookup` formula (`Row` number), minus one because the starting reference (`$A$1`) is one so it will over shot by one. `[starting row(1) + value row(4) = 5]` and we are looking for row 4 (this on image above example).

`10` - Distance from `$A$1` in `Columns`, similar as in rows `K` is the 11th letter of the Alphabet so we need `11 - 1` to give the correct column from the starting column `A`.

`e.g.: If you need column Q then 17-1=16, you put 16 in the column part of the offset`

`=OFFSET($A$1,AA6-1,10)`

Example :
[image]

For the `Subtask` in particular you seem to be getting the data from a different sheet, so you can put a `VLOOKUP` around the return from `OFFSET`.

`=VLOOKUP("*"&OFFSET($A$1,AA6-1,23)&"*",Sheet1!C:C,1,FALSE)`

`"*"&OFFSET($A$1,AA6-1,23)&"*` is the value were looking for, the `"*"` around the `OFFSET` means that the value might have different text before or after the value, `Sheet1!C:C` is your range on a different sheet, `1` is the column return value and `False` is looking for exact match

**Edit subtasks simplified:**

You might need to change some values, see image to understand better where they fit.

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,MATCH(VLOOKUP(AB6,K:X,14,FALSE),Sheet2!B:B,0)+COUNTIF($AD$5:AD5,"<>")-1,2)`

Formula breakdown from the inside out:

`AB6` - `Employee ID` for the example `Result e.g: 10004`.

`VLOOKUP(AB6,K:X,14,FALSE)` - This `VLOOKUP` will find the `Employee ID` and return Column `X` Department for that `Employee ID`. `Result e.g: "Software"`

`MATCH("Software",Sheet1!B:B,0)` - This will find the first match of `"Software"` in `Sheet1!` range `B:B`. Change the sheet and range to where your Table `Classification/Department` is. `Result e.g: 11`

`COUNTIF($AD$5:AD5,"<>")` - This points at the cell above and counts if different than empty `""` (the `"<>"` on the formula is a `Excel quirk`), this is a way to increment a counter, other ways of doing this is to type a number(increment manually on subsequent formulas) or to point/give reference to a cell (`+A1`) that contains a number increment. When you drag the formula down this will give `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` etc. `Result e.g: 0 for the first iteration`

`OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,11+0-1,2)` - The will start at `Sheet1!$A$1` cell (being that `Sheet1` is the sheet with the table) and add the numbers `11+0-1` to row and `2` to columns, which will result in `A+2` = `C` and `1 + 11+0-1` = `11`, `C11` is the cell where the value `010 Feature Design, ...` is, hence returning that value. `Result e.g: 010 Feature Design, ...`.

P.S.: To populate `Employee Name`s you can use a simple `VLOOKUP("10004",K:X,2,FALSE)` the previous formula posted resulted from me thinking that employees could have more then one `Classification/Department`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is kinda what I was trying to do. Please see the screen shot below of the data set. https://www.screencast.com/t/6yaN1zoMda4h    https://www.screencast.com/t/LPFR15lQhCyh

Comment: @JamesWilliams If your happy with the answer please accept it ^^

Comment: These are the screen shots of an example of the data sources.  If you could help me figure out how to create a code that it returns the list of the software tasks, as well as the employee id, name  https://www.screencast.com/t/6yaN1zoMda4h       https://www.screencast.com/t/LPFR15lQhCyh

Comment: Here is what the example output should be.https://www.screencast.com/t/dvYTSyYhVDzk

Comment: @JamesWilliams Just edited the code with an explanation to help you implement the table.

Comment: Thanks! But I need the each subtask in its entire form for each department. Meaning: All of the software subtasks generate off of the software department classification.I figured out how to generate the appropriate number of rows. Now I need to generate the reflective subtasks. see picture. The subtasks are hard wired in, not calculated. (thank you for adding the pictures, 
I have no idea how that works) https://www.screencast.com/t/xtew0JeAeTbt

Comment: Your question keeps growing ^^. So you need to list ALL the subtasks of a give role/department? And an employee can belong to multiple departments? And on the original data you only have the department/role on the subtask department column?

Comment: No, one department for employees. I just need all subtasks of a given department.

Comment: I appreciate your help; however, I think your formula is assuming there is some connection between the data lists. There are no connections between the subtask source and the employee source. The only data point I can drive to get the subtasks is Department. The individuals themselves do not come naturally associated with the department.

Comment: @JamesWilliams I was under the assumption that the employee was tied to a department and the department tied to it's subtasks. If I were to post a VBA solution would it be easier for you to implement it?

Comment: You are correct. I guess I dont understand the offset function. Is it possible to do a vlookup and just have it return the value that is x number cells down from the valid return? Currently I have the subtasks in order. So if I could do if(vlookup(department,departmentsubtasklist,2,0)=cellabove, vlookup(department,departmentsubtasklist,2,0)+#rows,vlookup(department,departmentsubtaskslist,2,0)?

Comment: @JamesWilliams That's exactly what the last formula I posted does, unfortunately `VLOOKUP` doesn't allow for `ADDRESS` with means we cannot `OFFSET` (add rows). I'll simplify the formula to the maximum and give a descriptive explanation of the pieces. BTW The formula is so big because we are first finding the employee to know the department to find the subtasks.

Comment: Thank you so much. I look forward to the modification.

Comment: @JamesWilliams Just simplified the formula and did a (more or less) step by step of what you need to do to implement the formula, if you take it by steps you should get the `Result e.g.:` mentioned on the edit. I mentioned there as well that the formulas before this edit are for a much more complex data format `(multiple departments and entries per employee)`, so you could maybe replace them with some `VLOOKUP`s.